# TimeoutError returned while connecting via ssh while using splitcopy

Tags: python, ssh, router

I use the splitcopy python library to copy contents that are usually large from my server to the router. They work fine on all setups excepts for one setup where I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.5 support will be dropped in the next release ofcryptography. Please upgrade your Python.
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
skipping publickey ssh auth as root != andy
root@andy's password:
ssh authentication succeeded
TimeoutError returned while connecting via ssh:
```

What can be the possible reasons that I am running into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons here - is your `SSH` server alive and well? Does the `firewall` allow the `port 22` traffic? If `port 22` traffic is allowed, will it allow traffic from your `CIDR` block?

Ask yourselves these questions, you might figure out the problem.

Comment: I checked that my server is alive, there are no firewall filters. How do I chekc whether the traffic is allowed from my CIDR block? @Aparna Chaganti

Comment: Rules that allow hosts from a certain CIDR range are usually defined in the firewall. I have no idea about your firewall and networking setup. You can do a 'tcpdump' and/or 'traceroute' to track your packets and their contents .( on both sides of the communication if its possible )